# Conda `update --all` prevent downgrade

Tags: conda, miniconda

I have the following problem: currently some packages I use are only available in outdated version in the `defaults` repository, and so I use `conda-forge` as well. However, due to channel-priority, conda keeps trying to downgrade these packages - in particular, `jupyterlab` in version >=3.0

So at the moment, I always do `conda update --all "jupyterlab>=3.0" "nodejs>=12.0"`, which is tedious, in particular once we add more version specifications.

How can I set up `conda` to "fix" my version requirement? Note that I still want to prioritize the defaults channel over the conda-forge channel, so as soon as `jupyterlab>=3.0` becomes available in `defaults`, it should switch automatically.

Answer (score 0):

This specific behavior can be forced with [`--strict-channel-priority`](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/commands/update.html#Solver%20Mode%20Modifiers) , but (opinion incoming) switching everything over to the `conda-forge` channel would be a better solution in general.

Comment: This doesn't address the issue at all. In principle, I wouldn't care so much whether the packages come from defaults or conda-forge. But switching everything to conda-forge actually ends up downgrading some other packages I do not want downgraded.

Comment: If you just want the newest version of everything, no matter where it comes from, you can use `--no-channel-priority`. If you want to specify where each version of each package comes from, and also set bounds on the versions of each, you can use `--file` and point to a custom specification.